# Setting FreeSurfer subject directory through matlab

Tags: linux, directory, command-prompt

Trying to fun FreeSurfer through Matlab and need to set the subject directory for output files.

Any ideas why...

```
curSub = 'subject_path'

system(['export SUBJECTS_DIR=' curSub])
```

...won't work?

When I run any FreeSurfer processes it tries to make the subject folder in the local/freesurfer/subjects directory.

Answer (score 1):

Because 'system' executes the export command in a system shell, which might not be the shell from which you started MATLAB, and the new definition of SUBJECTS_DIR is only visible in the daughter shell, which is probably an unknown one then.
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html

You should instead use setenv('SUBJECTS_DIR',curSub)
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html